# How to write stored procedure use SP_HELPTEXT for getting information of objects belong to another database

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have a db lets called it A in that database I have procedure backup which get all creation information of another database which is B.

Now the problem when I am trying to use `SP_HELPTEXT` inside my procedure backup it give the information of database A. Any suggestion to make within database B?

Scenario:

I need to backup all functions in database B. My procedure which do that job is in database A. I used dynamic SQL to reach the names of functions when I want to get the body of them by using `SP_HELPTEXT` I stoped here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against `sp_helptext` in general.

```
SELECT [schema] = s.name, [object] = o.name, m.definition 
  FROM otherdatabase.sys.sql_modules AS m
  INNER JOIN otherdatabase.sys.objects AS o
  ON m.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN otherdatabase.sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];
```

If you need the database name to be dynamic, you can do:

```
DECLARE @db sysname = N'otherdatabase';

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(520) = @db + '.sys.sp_executesql';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT [schema] = s.name, 
    [object] = o.name, m.definition 
  FROM sys.sql_modules AS m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
  ON m.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```